# How to pip install for certain version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I need to install `requests` globally for python3

```
pip install requests
```

installs it for python2.7.

How to do this without `virtualenv` ?

I have no `pip3`.

Same problem for `lxml` installation.

Comment: Please improve your question's quality. You might take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some python packages cannot be installed with `pip`, one possible reason is that they have binaries included that are platform-depend (e.g. `wxPython`, can be searched by `pip` but cannot be installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve conflicting installation sites always follow the following steps:

1. To  install for python3 use: `python3 -m pip install requests`
2. For python2 use: `python2 -m pip install [any_module]`

This will prevent any conflicts, which I hope is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the rate of -2 in your problem, and I don't think I can understand your question well, either. I will try too help.

Now you have python 2.7 and python3, when your virtualenv is not activate, 'pip' is for python2.x and 'pip3' is for python3.x

there is no necessary to think about Why pip is for python2.7

you can choose python3 when you create a virtualenv environment folder:

$ virtualenv --python=python3 aaa

$ cd aaa

$ . bin/activate

now 'pip install' is for python3.x

Comment: I did that. But, as you can see `There is a problem installing lxml via virtualenv`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `pip install lxml` and succeed, not sure the situation you encountered.

`pip` command uses the "default" Python version in your system, you HAVE to check the output of `pip --version` to figure out which version it belongs to.

"`pip` is for Python2" is not always correct, at least on my machine.

If you want to install packages without virtualenv, you have to install them globally, `sudo pip install requests` does that.

But think twice and try more a little bit before you do, we usually not install python packages globally.